# NodeJS - Map forEach Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with node. I have an array of ids. I want to filter them based on a response of a call of other API. So i want to populate each id and know if they assert or not the filter i am doing based on the API.

I am using async/await. I found that the best approach is using Promises.all, but this is not working as expected. What i am doing wrong?

```
    static async processCSGOUsers (groupId, parsedData) {

        let steamIdsArr = [];

        const usersSteamIds = parsedData.memberList.members.steamID64;

        const filteredUsers = await Promise.all(usersSteamIds.map(async (userId) => {
            return csGoBackpack(userId).then( (response) => {
                    return response.value > 40;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return err;
                });
        }));

        Object.keys(usersSteamIds).forEach(key => {
            steamIdsArr.push({
                steam_group_id_64: groupId,
                steam_id_64: usersSteamIds[key]
            });
        });

        return UsersDao.saveUsers(steamIdsArr);
}
```

Apart from that, it is happening something weird. When i was debbuging this, data parameters on this method is coming fine. When i reach on the line of the Promise.all i got a "reference error" on each parameter. I do not why.

Comment: You're not using `filteredUsers` anywhere, but even if you were, it'd be an array of booleans, not the filtered array of users as you seem to expect based on that variable name.

Comment: sorry, that filteredUsers goes on the Object.keys (forget it to update). You are right on boolean values, but i am not getting that too :/

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct any mistakes if you want.

Comment: I don't think you want to call `Object.keys` on an array? And you should use `map` instead of `forEach`+`push`.

Comment: I am stupid, i realized that i was passing an object not an array. So i have to populate each entry on the Object and filter based on your responses :D

Answer (score 2):

Wait for all responses, then filter based on the results:

```
const responses = await Promise.all(usersSteamIds.map(csGoBackpack));
// responses now contains the array of responses for each user ID
// filter the user IDs based on the corresponding result
const filteredUsers = usersSteamIds.filter((_, index) => responses[index].value > 40);
```

Comment: This looks about right, based on what I'd expect the API to be doing.

Comment: Nice answer! :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a module, you can do this kind of stuff in a straightforward way using [these utilities](https://github.com/toniov/p-iteration)